java/kotlin bytecode parsing
How can I extract all the string literal from java/kotlin byte code using ow2 asm library?
I am currently using gradle's Instrumentation API + asm library to parse the bytecode. I am not able to understand asm documentation very well and I need to extract all the string literal from the bytecode and replace them with a function call.

This question is far too broad, and given that you posted it in 'mobile development', it sounds like you want to apply this to android which works completely differently.

Yes I want to do some build time transformation
reference : https://blog.sentry.io/bytecode-transformations-the-android-gradle-plugin/

A string literal is a source code artifact. Transforming bytecode is about compiled code and the available options depend on the actual use case. Replacing a use of a string literal as a value is simple, though you can’t distinguish a string literal from other compile time constants (but this distinction might not matter). On the other hand, changing a case label of a switch is very complicated, requiring significant rewriting of the code. But changing a constant string to a function call in an annotation is just impossible.
